# Changing nameservers in WHM

Tags: nameserver

I have a WHM that was configured to have the following NS.

```
ns1.domain-old.example
ns2.domain-old.example
```

However `domain-old.example` expired and is already in the open market. Therefore I asked the WHM support to change my nameserver to my new domain called `domain-new.example` that I purchased on GoDaddy. The support told be that they are already changed the NS to `ns1.domain-new.example` and `ns2.domain-new.example`. Unfortunately, when I tried to change the NS on GoDaddy I keep getting this message.

> Nameserver    Actions
>
> `ns1.domain-new.example`
>
> Unavailable
>
> `ns2.domain-new.example`
>
> Unavailable
>
> The data provided cannot be used, please correct it and resubmit your
> request.

Oh and the `domain-new.example` cPanel is on WHM too.

GoDaddy DNS settings
[image]

Alright, the reason I am creating ns1 and ns2 is we are a hosting reseller for our web development client. The previous NS got expired and already in the open market. Since we have our company domain hosted as well in our cPanel I asked our hosting provider to change the old NS's to a new NS using our company domain. However, I haven't done any setup aside from what our hosting provider did in WHM which is they just changed the NS to the domain I provided.

Currently (for `domain-new.example`) in my GoDaddy I am using the NS's of Cloudflare. Which also adds additional complexity and confusion to me on how to achieve what we need.

To give a full picture of my setup and what I wanted to achieve.

In WHM I have.

1. `domain-client-1.example`
2. `domain-client-2.example`
3. `domain-client-3.example`
4. `domain-client-4.example`
5. `domain-client-5.example`
6. `domain-new.example` (our company address)

Now these domains below are registered to different domain provider.

1. `domain-client-1.example`
2. `domain-client-2.example`
3. `domain-client-3.example`
4. `domain-client-4.example`
5. `domain-client-5.example`

And right now the above 5 domains are all down since all of them are using `ns1.domain-old.example` and `ns2.domain-old.example`.

The problem is what should be the solution to this problem since the `domain-old.example` is already in the open market and I don't want to require it again.

So the solution I came through is to change the nameservers configured in our WHM. Unfortunately, changing nameservers in WHM seems not enough and requires additional steps which is I am not sure at this moment.

`domain-new.example` is using Cloudflare nameservers. How can I make the 5 domains mentioned above to run again? They require nameservers which currently the `ns1.domain-new.example` and `ns2.domain-new.example` are both not working.

Comment: How long have you waited for `new-domain.example`? When was it registered and set-up?

Comment: It is registered almost a year.

Comment: Actually I am using that domain as our company website address.

Comment: Does ns1 and `ns2.new-domain.example` exist? For how long? Who is the SOA for `new-domain.example`?

Comment: I am not sure for ns1 and ns2. But in Godday DNS settings they are not there.

Comment: Without knowing the actual sequence of steps taken, it sounds like you haven't [created nameservers for your domain name](https://www.godaddy.com/help/add-my-own-host-names-as-nameservers-12320) in GoDaddy yet, so they're not resolving to your WHM hosting account. You can confirm this by doing a nameserver WHOIS check [here](https://www.internic.net/whois.html) (e.g., select Nameserver and enter `ns1.domain-new.example`). If that's the case, create them and then add them as [custom nameservers](https://www.godaddy.com/help/set-custom-nameservers-for-domains-registered-with-godaddy-12317).

Comment: Now that you updated your question, I am really confused. What are you trying to do??

Comment: I mean, why are you creating ns1 and ns2? Are they to point to the Cloudflare name servers? If that is the case, you can just create a CNAME record for ns1 and ns2 pointing to the Cloudflare name servers.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to change your name servers from custom back to default.

Then compare your DNS records with the ones added by Cloudflare.
If you did that, you can find any missing DNS records in Cloudflare that you must add first, then you can change these in GoDaddy and have Cloudflare scan the DNS for your domain again. Then finally change the name servers back to the custom ones from Cloudflare:

[image]